# How to remove "taskbar" tabs?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, taskbar

Here's how, all of a sudden, my Ubuntu desktop started to look like:

[image]

A Windows-like task bar appeared at the bottom after more than a year of using the same Ubuntu without any such surprises. Does anyone know what that is and how to get rid of that thing?